# Proof that $(a,b) = \{ta +(1-t)b\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a, b$ be numbers that belong to the reals with $a < b$. Let $(a,b)$ be an interval that belongs to the reals.

$(a,b) = \left\{ta + (1-t)b \mid 0 < t < 1 \right\}$

how do I prove that

$(a,b) = \left\{ ta + (1-t)b \right\}$ and $\left\{ ta + (1-t)b \right\} = (a,b)$

Comment: You are missing a condition on $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a<x<b\iff0<x-a<b-a\iff0<\frac{x-a}{b-a}<1.$$

Then with $t:=\dfrac{x-a}{b-a}$,

$$0<t<1\iff0<t(b-a)<b-a\iff a<t(b-a)+a<b.$$